# Read php page content from android using eclipse

Tags: java, php, android

Please I want a very simple way to read the content of my php page from my android app! I don't want jSon or something, all I want is to have the content of the php page a String in java! Thank youu in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    String html = "";
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        str.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    html = str.toString();



   Log.i('HtmlContent',+html)
```

Comment: I tried the same code and it wasn't running but now I figured why, it's because of internet permissions in the manifest xml, thank you anyway!