# Get html source code: indexoutofboundsexception index 0 size 0

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

There is a method that i am using to get a website html source code.
this method works fine in a simple java project, but in an android project "indexoutofboundsexception index 0 size 0" exeption accurs.

the method and the log included:

```
private String getUrlSource(String url_str) throws Exception {



    String htmlText="";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_str);
        URLConnection spoof = url.openConnection();
        spoof.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)" );
        in =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            htmlText=htmlText + inputLine + "\n";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
    Log.d("getURL", "done");
    return htmlText;

}
```

[image]

the Exeption is in this line:

`in =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));`

Thanks for any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285981/read-php-page-content-from-android-using-eclipse/18286023#18286023

Comment: @AmitPrajapati: the solution mentioned in that link gives the same exeption for me!!

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persist, my suggestion is use Vector object as second parameter to set attribute.  Retrieve Vector from JSP and extract your data from Vector object.

Comment: can you explain more? such as including code.how should i do it?