# Get web page content (with json array)

Tags: android, http

I am trying to get my web page content (i have in the page json array), and i can not find a way to do it, evry code i found in google dont work and crash the application..

I need help!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) ?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question in more detail other wise it may be voted down by some one because of unclear question

Comment: I dont want help with json, i just want to get web page content, and this is it.

Comment: yes you can. do you have url for that ?

Comment: Yes: http://www.nirberko.info/android/index.php

Comment: try this code this is track by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285981/read-php-page-content-from-android-using-eclipse/18286023#18286023

Comment: Amit, it's dont work... It crashes the app: http://pastebin.com/ZCHJ6zxU

Comment: you need to give internet permission

Comment: i have one, look: http://pastebin.com/5fXh3dMf

Comment: this is not html page this one is json you need to access with JSONObject

Comment: still dont work: http://pastebin.com/sbuV79Au

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/

This library allows you (can do many things) to take a json from a specific url in a very simple way. I know it quite well and i never had any problems.

I'll show you an example:

Json on your page

```
{
  "account":{
  "username":"nirbe"
  }
}
```

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  private AQuery aQuery;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    // First of all, create a new AQuery object
    aQuery = new AQuery(this);

    // Do your ajax call
    aQuery.ajax("http://www.nirberko.info/android/index.php", JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {

      @Override
      public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {
        if (json != null) {
          try {
            // Here you will receive your json object,
            // use it as you wish
            String username = json.getJSONObject("account").getString("username");
            // In case, you can directly update your view here
            aQuery.id(R.id.tv_name).text(username);
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

my_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great! but now i want to create a static function and i dont now how to do this (i stuck here): http://pastebin.com/KCyPMUSe

Comment: Help? I need it for tomorrow...

Comment: Not so easy, because the callback is async and that function will always return "".
I think you should open a new question (i can try to answer there) or we will go out of topic.
if you found my answer useful, please accept it.

Comment: English is not my first language, so it's hard to me to explain, if you can help me here, it's great!

Comment: I'm very sorry, but i have to post some code and write a little explanation. I can't do it here, in comments (mods don't like that).
I suggest you to take a look at android handler ;)

Comment: So if you can, just send me the solution in pastebin, and i can understand it alone.